It was only recently that he got well

Only recently he got well => Only recently did he get well.

The inversion sentence above is correct and more common and formal in written Englsih as per my knowledge.

It was only recently that he got well.

My question is: in the hyperbolic sentence(it was...that s+v) above, can I invert the sentence as below? If I can invert, is it idiomatic?

It was only recently that did he get well.


We say "Get well soon" to wish someone a speedy recovery from illness or accident, but it's usually You'll get better after being treated with antibiotics and He only got better recently.

Negative inversions of this type  occur at the main clause,  not at the subordinate clause.
Wikipedia explains under its Uses of subject–auxiliary inversion section:

Most of these uses of inversion are restricted to main clauses; they are not found in subordinate clauses.

Read further for some exceptions.
Wikipedia
Cambridge Dictionary has this example under its Negative adverbs: hardly, seldom, etc. section:

Little did we know that we would never meet again.

Cambridge Dictionary
This version is hence the correct one:

It was only recently that he got well.

This isn’t:

*It was only recently that did he get well.


You mean inverted version can't be used in this structure of "it is/was X that S+V" (where X is subject, object, adverbial clause, modifier)?

There shouldn’t be inversion in the subordinate clause despite the presence of only.  Try bringing only to the front of the matrix clause, and we will see that the matrix clause undergoes inversion; the subordinate clause doesn’t:
Only recently was it discovered that he was sick for a long time.
